# TInputDirWizardPage with Radio Buttons

Tags: radio-button, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need a setup page with two radio buttons. Clicking the second button should enable an input to define a path (Like it's done in `TInputDirWizardPage`).

Is it possible to customize `TInputDirWizardPage` for my needs?

Or do I need to build a `CustomPage` and define the controls by myself?
If the second question will be answered with yes, how am I able to use the "directory input" (from the `TInputDirWizardPage`), or is it also neccessary to build this on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly guessed you have several options:

1. Start with `TWizardPage` and build everything from scratch
2. Start with `TInputDirWizardPage` and add the radio buttons
3. Start with `TInputOptionWizardPage` and add the edit box

The second option probably involves least customization. Though it needs a hack from [Is it possible to allow a user to skip a TInputDirWizardPage in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25025307/850848)

```pascal
{ WORKAROUND }
{ Checkboxes and Radio buttons created on runtime do }
{ not scale their height automatically. }
{ See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30469660/850848 }
procedure ScaleFixedHeightControl(Control: TButtonControl);
begin
  Control.Height := ScaleY(Control.Height);
end;

var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;
  DefaultLocationButton: TRadioButton;
  CustomLocationButton: TRadioButton;
  OldNextButtonOnClick: TNotifyEvent;

procedure LocationButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Page.Edits[0].Enabled := CustomLocationButton.Checked;
  Page.Buttons[0].Enabled := CustomLocationButton.Checked;
end;

procedure NextButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  PrevDir: string;
begin
  { Do not validate, when "default location" is selected }
  if (WizardForm.CurPageID = Page.ID) and DefaultLocationButton.Checked then
  begin
    PrevDir := Page.Values[0];
    Page.Values[0] := GetWinDir; { Force value to pass validation }
    OldNextButtonOnClick(Sender);
    Page.Values[0] := PrevDir;
  end
    else
  begin
    OldNextButtonOnClick(Sender);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpWelcome,
    'Select Personal Data Location', 'Where should personal data files be stored?',
    '', False, 'New Folder');
  Page.Add('');

  DefaultLocationButton := TRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  DefaultLocationButton.Parent := Page.Surface;
  DefaultLocationButton.Top := Page.Edits[0].Top;
  DefaultLocationButton.Caption := 'Use default location';
  DefaultLocationButton.Checked := True;
  DefaultLocationButton.OnClick := @LocationButtonClick;
  ScaleFixedHeightControl(DefaultLocationButton);
  
  CustomLocationButton := TRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  CustomLocationButton.Parent := Page.Surface;
  CustomLocationButton.Top :=
    DefaultLocationButton.Top + DefaultLocationButton.Height + ScaleY(8);
  CustomLocationButton.Caption := 'Use custom location';
  CustomLocationButton.OnClick := @LocationButtonClick;
  ScaleFixedHeightControl(DefaultLocationButton);

  Page.Buttons[0].Top :=
    Page.Buttons[0].Top +
    ((CustomLocationButton.Top + CustomLocationButton.Height + ScaleY(8)) -
      Page.Edits[0].Top);
  Page.Edits[0].Top :=
    CustomLocationButton.Top + CustomLocationButton.Height + ScaleY(8);
  Page.Edits[0].Left := Page.Edits[0].Left + ScaleX(16);
  Page.Edits[0].Width := Page.Edits[0].Width - ScaleX(16);
  Page.Edits[0].TabOrder := CustomLocationButton.TabOrder + 1;
  Page.Buttons[0].TabOrder := Page.Edits[0].TabOrder + 1;

  LocationButtonClick(nil); { Update edit for initial state of buttons }

  OldNextButtonOnClick := WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick;
  WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick := @NextButtonOnClick;
end;
```

[image]

[image]

---

*More general question on the topic: [Inno Setup Placing image/control on custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696537/850848)*.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you again.