# Inno Setup - multiple installation directories with checkboxes

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to create an installer that has selectable versions and associated directories like this example:

[image: inno example]

I have figured out how to add checkboxes to items on the "Tasks" page, and the "Select Destination" pages is self explanatory... but I can't figure out how to combine these into one page.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite complex page to implement in Inno Setup.

Implementing it based on tasks is not the best way, imo. I would start with [`TInputDirWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputDirWizardPage) (created by [`CreateInputDirPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage)) and add the checkboxes.

These two questions contain almost everything you need:

- [Inno Setup with three destination folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25657175/850848)
- [TInputDirWizardPage with Radio Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49358778/850848)